# Best way to organize communication between Vue.js components in this case?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have an array

```js
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "title": "Task #1",
    "description": "Task description",
    "solutions": [
      {
        "solutionId": 0,
        "text": "First solution text",
        "isMarked": true
      },
      {
        "solutionId": 1,
        "text": "Second solution text",
        "isMarked": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Task #2",
    "description": "Task description",
    "solutions": [
      {
        "solutionId": 0,
        "text": "First solution text",
        "isMarked": true
      },
      {
        "solutionId": 1,
        "text": "Second solution text",
        "isMarked": true
      },
      {
        "solutionId": 2,
        "text": "Third solution text",
        "isMarked": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

It represents a list of tasks and solution variants.

I need an opportunity to toggle value `isMarked` of solution to `true/false` just with click on it.

I created a components structure like this:

```js
// index.vue
<template>
   <div class="task-list">
      <Task v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id" :task="task" />
   </div>
</template>

<script>
// ...
data() {
   return {
      tasks: [/* the array of tasks */]
   }
}
</script>
```

```js
// task.vue
<template>
   <div>
      <h1>{{ task.title }}</h1>
      <p>{{ task.description }}</p>
      <SolutionsList :solutions="task.solutions" />
   </div>
</template>

// ...
```

```js
// solutionsList.vue
<template>
   <div>
      <Solution v-for="solution in solutions" :key="solution.id" :solution="solution" />
   </div>
</template>

// ...
```

```js
// solution.vue
<template>
<div>
      <p>{{ solution.text }}</p>
      <span @click="toggleMark">{{ markLabel }}</span>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
// ...
computed: {
   markLabel() {
      return solution.isMarked ? 'Unmark' : 'Mark'
   }
},
methods: {
   toggleMark() {
      // ???
   }
}
</script>
```

I can store this state in Vuex for example, not in `data()` of `index.vue`. And I need to make an API call with to change  `isMarked` value for a clicked solution of a task.

And here is the question: what is the best way to do that?
If `solutionId` were unique as a last resort I can iterate over all tasks in Vuex to find that `solutionId` and change state there. But in this case `solutionId`'s are not unique for all tasks.

What solutions do I see:

1. Pass `id` of a task to each `Solution` with separate props. But in this case I need to create a lot of props for every component if `Solution` component is deep nested and it can be deep nested.
2. It will be the best just emit `toggleMark` event from `Solution` component and catch it in `Task` component but in my case of deep nesting `Solution` component I need to re-emit it in each parent component on a way to `Task`.
3. I can call a Vuex action just in `Solution` component to mutate `isMarked`. But I still need a task `id` to find a parent task which holds this clicked solution.
4. I can use an Event Bus, but it's not really favored in modern approaches.
5. I can make another computed method at `index.vue` and map each `solution` with their parent task `id` to make a new field `taskId` for example and pass the result object instead of `tasks`. But it looks a bit dirty way.
6. I can use `provide / inject` at least. And for this case it will be good solution. But what if `Solution` wasn't a child component of a `Task` and it will be in random place.

It's just a lightweight example of a problem. Sure it will be perfect just throw away `SolutionsList` and emit `toggleMark` event but intermediate components to `Solution` component could be a lot or it may not be a child of `Task` component for example.

Please tell me how can I solve this problem in a best way?

Comment: Since you are dealing with a fair amount of nested components I would lean towards a vuex action. Especially since you mentioned you have to hit an api to change isMarked

Comment: @LLai yes, vuex is a good choice but the problem is how to find target task component having only not unique solution id and mutate exactly that solution at parent task.

Comment: hmm you could append the task id to each solution objeect when you initially fetch the data. so now each solution has a `solutionId` and `taskId`